# python3 помогите с bs4 найти элемент по классу

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, beautiful-soup, bs4

у меня есть такой код:

```
def get_html_hidemy(site):
    r = requests.get(site)
    return r.text

def get_page_data_hidemy(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    line = soup.find_all('div', class_='table_block').find("table").find('tbody').find_all('tr')

    for tr in line:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        ip = td[0].text
        port = td[1].text
        country = td[2].text.replace('\xa0', '')
        types = td[4].text.replace('\r\n\t\t\t\t\t', '').replace('\r\n      ', '')

        data = {'ip': ip,
                'Порт': port,
                'Страна': country,
                'Тип': types}

        print(data)

def hidemy():
    url_hidemy = 'https://hidemy.name/ru/proxy-list/#list'
    get_page_data_hidemy(get_html_hidemy(url_hidemy))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    hidemy()
```

и пишет ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Иван\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Иван\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Иван\Desktop\pypi\bot_bomber_admin.py", line 105, in hidemy
    get_page_data_hidemy(get_html_hidemy(url_hidemy))
  File "C:\Users\Иван\Desktop\pypi\bot_bomber_admin.py", line 79, in get_page_data_hidemy
    line = soup.find_all('table', class_='table_block').find('tbody').find_all('tr')
  File "C:\Users\Иван\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2173, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

что я делаю не так?

Comment: `line = soup.find_all('div', class_='table_block')` замените на `line = soup.find('div', class_='table_block')`

Comment: @Danis line = soup.find('div', class_='table_block').find("table").find('tbody').find_all('tr')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше поучите `bs4`, так нельзя его использовать.
Вот код который решит вашу проблему и не укорачивайте код по максимуму, а то всё перестанет работать)

```
def get_html_hidemy(site):
    r = requests.get(site)
    return r.text

def get_page_data_hidemy(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    line = soup.find('div', class_='table_block')
    proxies = line.find_all("tr")

    for tr in proxies:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        ip = td[0].text
        port = td[1].text
        country = td[2].text.replace('\xa0', '')
        types = td[4].text.replace('\r\n\t\t\t\t\t', '').replace('\r\n      ', '')

        data = {'ip': ip,
                'Порт': port,
                'Страна': country,
                'Тип': types}

        print(data)

def hidemy():
    url_hidemy = 'https://hidemy.name/ru/proxy-list/#list'
    get_page_data_hidemy(get_html_hidemy(url_hidemy))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    hidemy()
```

Comment: А чтобы не било никаких казусов ещё рекомендую место `lxml` использовать `html.parser` тоесть `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')`